# System.Text.Json Serializer returning unwanted value in Json string property (\\u00222\\u0022)

Tags: c#, json, serialization, system.text.json

I want to serialize a object that has a string property with value: `"    if(_inputs.loopInput == \"2\"){\n        return true\n    }\n    else{\n        return false;\n    }"`

The issue is that, when I do serialize it, the value transforms it self in: `"    if(_inputs.loopInput == \\u00222\\u0022){\\n        return true\\n    }\\n    else{\\n        return false;\\n    }\"`

I would like to get rid of this \u00222\u0022 in the escaped "2".

Does any one know why this happens?

Before this, I was using Newtonsoft, and when I invoke the serialize method, I pass this parameters:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_data,
                            Formatting.None,
                            settings ?? new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

Getting this result:

```
"{\"code\":\"    if(_inputs.loopInput == \\\"2\\\"){\\n        return true\\n    }\\n    else{\\n        return false;\\n    }\"
```

I would like to get the same result, but using System.Text.Json.

This is how I am using:

```
JsonSerializer.Serialize(lambdaCallBody);
```

Summing up...

Desired serialize result (using NewtonSoft):

```
"{\"code\":\"    if(_inputs.loopInput == \\\"2\\\"){\\n        return true\\n    }\\n    else{\\n        return false;\\n    }\",\"inputs\":{\"loopInput\":\"2\"},\"execInfo\":{\"tenant\":\"__TEST__agentFlowV3\",\"flowId\":\"5e9736ff554defb30152a9a2\",\"jobId\":\"1586968416402\"}}"
```

What I am getting (using System.Text.Json):

```
"{\"code\":\"    if(_inputs.loopInput == \\u00222\\u0022){\\n        return true\\n    }\\n    else{\\n        return false;\\n    }\",\"inputs\":{\"loopInput\":\"\\u00222\\u0022\"},\"execInfo\":{\"tenant\":\"__TEST__agentFlowV3\",\"flowId\":\"5e9736ff554defb30152a9a2\",\"jobId\":\"1586968416402\",\"mappingFunction\":null,\"functionReferences\":null}}"
```

Comment: `\u0022` is an encoded version of `"`

Comment: What is settings? is it defined somewhere else?

Comment: In the case that it works it is null, so the value used is new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore })

Comment: @OguzOzgul But this was when I was using NewtonSoft, now that I am using System.Text.Json, I do not pass any parameters. So its like: JsonSerializer.Serialize(lambdaCallBody)

Comment: Can you please show desired JSON output? Note that you can't really have unescaped quotes in JSON - make sure desired sample shows valid JSON.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Oh sorry, I just adited posting the Json returned using NewtonSoft. Notice that it just escapes one more time, insted of adding \u0022.

Comment: `System.Text.Json` escapes many more characters that is strictly necessary for the JSON standard.  For explanations and workarounds, see [dotnet core System.Text.Json unescape unicode string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58003293/3744182) and [Issues with System.Text.Json serializing Unicode characters (like emojis)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58738258/3744182).

Comment: In fact I think this may be a duplicate of those two, agree?  (I haven't tried running your code to make sure, but it looks the same.)

Comment: @dbc I will try it out, just a sec.

Comment: @dbc It is duplicate actually. It worked after a set the property Encoder = System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping in the JsonSerializerOptions. Thanks