# System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter - how to prevent breaking Unicode characters into escape sequences?

Tags: c#, json, unicode, encoding

I have a `JsonNode` to write to a file.
The JSON contains a string with a special character in it: "".

It's written as "\uD83D\uDC15" and it's not exactly what I want.
JSON files support UTF-8, and "" is a valid UTF-8 code point consisting of 4 bytes:
`0xF0` `0x9F` `0x90` `0xB6`.

Instead I get it translated to 12 bytes, just in case I would edit it on old terminal from the 80s. I'm not interested. I actually use Visual Studio Code for editing the file.

How to force writing without such unwanted translations?

BTW, the file is deserialized correctly, the deserialized string contains valid Unicode codepoint. So - basically the application works, however I'm super curious how to change the serialization behavior.

In case someone's too curious about the code, here it is:

```cs
public virtual void Save(JsonNode node, Stream stream) {
    if (node is null) return;
    using var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(stream, WriterOptions);
    node.WriteTo(writer, SerializerOptions);
}
```

...where `WriterOptions`:

```cs
public JsonWriterOptions WriterOptions { get; } = new() { Indented = true, SkipValidation = true };
```

...and `SerializerOptions`:

```cs
public JsonSerializerOptions SerializerOptions { get; } = new() { WriteIndented = true };
```

Here's an example project showing the issue:
https://github.com/HTD/JsonNodeUtfIssue/blob/master/JsonNodeUtfIssue/Program.cs

https://dotnetfiddle.net/73RxAd

Comment: When you use UTF-8 the characters 0x00 to 0x7F are standard.  The characters 0x80 to 0xFF are encoded and mapped to two byte unicode characters depending on the encoding used. So you need to use the same encoding methods on both client and server.

Comment: But there's only one way conversion - the original Unicode string is serialized. As I mentioned in the question - it is deserialized properly. The problem occurs when I just open the saved file with VS Code. I manually replaced the "\uD83D\uDC15" sequence to "", saved the file (in VS Code), and it opens with "" content. Also - it's still deserialized correctly by my code.

Comment: Compare you original file with the one received and look at differences.  The unicode characters cannot start on an odd byte count.

Comment: There is no original file, the file is generated by my app. When it's generated by the app, it has the Unicode sequences translated when opening it in VS Code. When I open it with my app, the translated sequences are decoded. I can replace the sequence for the character with VS Code and save it. It looks OK in VS Code and when opened in my app the result is identical.

Comment: Still you can compare the string that works with what doesn't work.

Comment: Check the example project I just added to the question: https://github.com/HTD/JsonNodeUtfIssue - it's shows better what is exactly happening than I can describe.

Comment: FYI - added a dotnetfiddle of your code

Comment: Try comparing both text strings with following : string[] results = text.ToCharArray().Select(x => ((int)x).ToString("X4")).ToArray();

Comment: I was curios and googled a bit, and found the following: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29374 | https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-encoding - but even when I use `UnicodeRanges.All` I am not getting the desired result, but I can see the option influencing the output eg. when I use `UnicodeRanges.None` it will encode all characters - All: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fMdlSH | None: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VLArNU

Comment: Seems like a bug in the encoder. I see the `AllowedUnicodeRanges` affects how the property names are encoded, it does nothing to strings themselves - which is, IMO, wrong. So it would probably take creating an own encoder to make it work.

Comment: I noticed that the translation is made on node creation. So - it's not the writer's fault.

Comment: same issue without a solution yet: [Issues with System.Text.Json serializing Unicode characters (like emojis)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58738258/995714)

Comment: If anyone interested, I made a workaround for this, a special decoding stream that fixes it...

Answer (score 1):

try

```
var jsonOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
   Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping
};

JsonSerializer.Serialize(message, jsonOptions);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my workaround. A decoding stream.

When `Utf8JsonWriter` writes UTF-8 bytes to the stream, my `Utf8DecodeStream` searches for Unicode escape sequences, decodes them to UTF-8 bytes and writes instead of original escape sequences.

It's relatively fast, because it doesn't use regular expressions, string search / replacement, string to number conversions, avoidable allocations and so on.

It operates directly on binary data (original stream's buffer). It may fail to replace a sequence when it's broken between 2 writes. In such case the file will not be damaged, just that one sequence will be left unchanged.

OK, there is one special case - if the block boundary will end breaking a long Unicode escape sequence into 2 valid 16-bit codes, it would result with invalid decoding, since 2 16-bit chars decoded to UTF-8 bytes and just concatenated won't produce the valid 32-bit UTF-8 code point.

BTW, I don't know if the `Utf8JsonWriter` would break writes in the middle of strings, it might write whole lines, or at least JSON tokens, so mentioned problems might never occur.

It's worth noting the class uses the escape sequence generated by `Utf8JsonWriter` - so, for speed, it doesn't decode sequences starting with "\U" or containing lower case hexadecimal digits. The support for different formats can easily be added.

**CAUTION:** The `Utf8JsonWriter` escapes Unicode sequences for a reason that is security. Do not decode if it might make the application vulnerable.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Decodes the Unicode escape sequences while writing UTF-8 stream.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// This is a workaround for a <see cref="Utf8JsonWriter"/> not doing it on its own.
/// </remarks>
public class Utf8DecodeStream : Stream {

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a Unicode escape sequence decoding stream over a writeable stream.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="stream">A writeable stream.</param>
    public Utf8DecodeStream(Stream stream) => InnerStream = stream;

#pragma warning disable CS1591

    public override bool CanRead => InnerStream.CanRead;

    public override bool CanSeek => InnerStream.CanSeek;

    public override bool CanWrite => InnerStream.CanWrite;

    public override long Length => InnerStream.Length;

    public override long Position { get => InnerStream.Position; set => InnerStream.Position = value; }

    public override void Flush() => InnerStream.Flush();

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) => InnerStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => InnerStream.Seek(offset, origin);

    public override void SetLength(long value) => InnerStream.SetLength(value);

#pragma warning restore CS1591

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the buffer with the Unicode sequences decoded.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="buffer">Buffer to write.</param>
    /// <param name="offset">Position in the buffer to start.</param>
    /// <param name="count">Number of bytes to write.</param>
    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) {
        bool sequenceFound = false;
        while (count > 0) {
            sequenceFound = false;
            for (int i = offset, n = offset + count; i < n; i++) {
                if (DecodeUtf8Sequence(buffer, i, out var sequence, out var bytesConsumed)) {
                    InnerStream.Write(buffer, offset, i - offset);
                    count -= i - offset;
                    InnerStream.Write(sequence);
                    offset = i + bytesConsumed;
                    count -= bytesConsumed;
                    sequenceFound = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!sequenceFound) {
                InnerStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
                count = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to decode one or more subsequent Unicode escape sequences into UTF-8 bytes.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="buffer">A buffer to decode.</param>
    /// <param name="index">An index to start decoding from.</param>
    /// <param name="result">An array containing UTF-8 representation of the sequence.</param>
    /// <param name="bytesConsumed">The length of the matched escape sequence.</param>
    /// <returns>True if one or more subsequent Unicode escape sequences is found.</returns>
    private static bool DecodeUtf8Sequence(byte[] buffer, int index, out byte[] result, out int bytesConsumed) {
        bytesConsumed = 0;
        result = Array.Empty<byte>();
        List<char> parts = new(2);
        while (DecodeChar(buffer, index, out var part)) {
            parts.Add(part);
            index += 6;
            bytesConsumed += 6;
        }
        if (parts.Count < 1) return false;
        result = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parts.ToArray());
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to decode a single Unicode escape sequence.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// "\uXXXX" format is assumed for <see cref="Utf8JsonWriter"/> output.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="buffer">A buffer to decode.</param>
    /// <param name="index">An index to start decoding from.</param>
    /// <param name="result">Decoded character.</param>
    /// <returns>True if a single Unicode sequnece is found at specified index.</returns>
    private static bool DecodeChar(byte[] buffer, int index, out char result) {
        result = (char)0;
        if (index + 6 >= buffer.Length || buffer[index] != '\\' || buffer[index + 1] != 'u') return false;
        int charCode = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            if (!DecodeDigit(i, buffer, index + 2, ref charCode)) return false;
        result = (char)charCode;
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to decode a single hexadecimal digit from a buffer.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Upper case is assumed for <see cref="Utf8JsonWriter"/> output.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="n">A zero-based digit index.</param>
    /// <param name="buffer">Buffer to decode.</param>
    /// <param name="index">Sequence index.</param>
    /// <param name="charCode">Character code reference.</param>
    /// <returns>True if the buffer contains a hexadecimal digit at <paramref name="index"/> + <paramref name="n"/>.</returns>
    private static bool DecodeDigit(int n, byte[] buffer, int index, ref int charCode) {
        var value = buffer[index + n];
        var shift = 12 - (n << 2);
        if (value is >= 48 and <= 57) charCode += (value - 48) << shift;
        else if (value is >= 65 and <= 70) charCode += (value - 55) << shift;
        else return false;
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Target stream.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Stream InnerStream;

}
```

Usage:

```cs
using var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(new Utf8DecodeStream(stream));
```

Example xUnit test:

```cs
[Fact]
public void Utf8DecodeStreamTest() {
    var test = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"\uD83D\uDC15 \uD83D\uDC15 \uD83D\uDC15");
    using var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var decoding = new Utf8DecodeStream(stream);
    decoding.Write(test);
    decoding.Flush();
    var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    Assert.Equal("  ", result);
}
```